# Angular Material Datepicker open on focus

Tags: angular, datepicker, internet-explorer-11

Is it possible to implement the [Angular 2/4/5 Material](https://github.com/angular/material2) datepicker in a way to have it open on focus of the input field that will also work in IE 11?

[Here's an example which works in every browser except IE 11.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u8rg3v-dxy26s?file=app/datepicker-overview-example.html)

Answer (score 0):

use [md2](https://github.com/Promact/md2/tree/master/src/lib/datepicker) and just set `[openOnFocus]=true`

for example

```
  <md2-datepicker [(ngModel)]="customStartDate"
                                        [placeholder]="'Start Date'"
                                        [mode]="'portrait'"
                                        [max]="today"
                                        [format]="'y-MM-dd'"
                                        class="pr-3"
                                        [openOnFocus]=true>
                        </md2-datepicker>
```

Comment: Thanks but using the current Material library I have is imperative to the project I'm working on

Comment: Md2 is also  Material library package